# Connectivity problems with Linksys RE1000

Tags: wireless-networking

Here is my mostly wireless setup:

1. [Linksys X3000](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/gateways/x3000) is used as an ADSL modem and a wi-fi router (lets say it provides ssid **NETWORK1**). Configured as 192.168.1.1, DHCP-server enabled here.
2. Two [Linksys RE1000](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/rangeexpanders/RE1000) range extenders are located in rooms neerby to increase the coverage of **NETWORK1** network (wireless connection to X3000). Configured with static IP as 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.5 respectively.
3. [D-Link DIR-300 NRU/B7](http://www.dlink.com/me/sr/support/product/dir-300-wireless-g-router?revision=deu_revb) is connectioned by wire to X3000, configured as an access point (DHCP-server disabled) with static IP of 192.168.1.2, providing wi-fi network **NETWORK2**.
4. The last range extender (also Linksys RE1000) is used to increase coverage of **NETWORK2**. It's configured as 192.168.1.4

When I connect to **NETWORK1** or **NETWORK2** provided by X3000 and DIR-3000 (without extenders) and ping 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.5 - everything is ok.

But when I connect to **NETWORK1** far from X3000 in an area of replicated signal by RE1000's 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.6 (I double-checked this case with inSSIDer app) I fail to ping 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.4.

Why it is so and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, let me answer my own question. The problem looks to be solved by replacing the Linksys RE1000 range extenders by a new one.